# Associated primes of the square of a monomial ideal

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals, primary-decomposition

Consider the ideal $J=(xy,yz,zx)$ in $R=\mathbb C[x,y,z]$. How to show that $(x,y,z) \in \mathrm{Ass}_R (R/J^2)$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A down-to-earth method is: find an element whose annihilator is $(x, y, z)$.

An element that seems to work here is $xyz+J^2$. It is nonzero in $R/J^2$, since $J^2$ consists only of polynomials whose terms of degree $\leq 3$ are $0$.

We have 
\begin{align*}
x \cdot  xyz=x^2yz=(xy)(xz) \in J^2, \\
y \cdot  xyz=xy^2z=(xy)(yz) \in J^2, \\
z \cdot  xyz=xyz^2=(xz)(yz) \in J^2,
\end{align*}
showing that $(x, y, z) \subseteq \mathrm{Ann} (xyz + J^2)$. On the other hand, $(x, y, z)$ is a maximal ideal and $1 \notin \mathrm{Ann} (xyz + J^2)$, so we conclude equality.

Comment: Thanks ... is there a similar way to show $(x,y,z) \in Ass_R (R/J^n), \forall n \ge 3$ ? I know this is true by some high tech method, but I would really like to see an elementary proof ...

Comment: @uno: Sure, just take e.g. $(xy)^{n-2}\cdot(xyz)=x^{n-1}y^{n-1}z$. This is still not $0$ in $R/J^n$ by the same degree argument, but $(x, y, z)$ kills it by the very same computation as above (simply because $(xy)^{n-2} \in J^{n-2}$), so you can again conclude that the annihilator is precisely $(x, y, z)$.