# Primary decomposition of powers of a monomial (edge) ideal in a three variable polynomial ring

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, monomial-ideals, primary-decomposition

Consider the ideal $J=(xy,yz,zx)$ in $R=\mathbb C[x,y,z]$. As seen here [Associated primes of the square of a monomial ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3156825/associated-primes-of-the-square-of-a-monomial-ideal)   , $Ass_R (R/J^n)=\{(x,y); (y,z);(z,x);(x,y,z)\}, \forall n \ge 2$.

My question is : What is an irredundant primary decomposition of $J^n$, for $n\ge 2$ ?

Definitely $J^n$ will be the intersection of four primary ideals and the primary components corresponding to $(x,y); (y,z)$ and $(z,x)$ will be unique because these are the minimal primes. Apart from this, I am not sure how to actually get a decomposition.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

For any subset $S \subseteq V := \{x,y,z\}$ write $I_S$ for the ideal generated by the variables in $S$. Then a few computations with [Macaulay2](http://www2.macaulay2.com/Macaulay2/) will start to convince you that the primary decomposition of $J^n$ consists of four ideals: $(I_S)^n$ for each subset $S$ of size two and the ideal $K + K'$ where $K = \langle x^n, y^n, z^n\rangle$ and $K'$ is generated by all monomials $x^ay^bz^c$ of degree $2n$ such that $0 < a,b,c < n$.

To prove this is the irredundant primary decomposition first prove that $J^n$ is the ideal generated by all monomials $x^ay^bz^c$ of degree $2n$ such that $0 \le a,b,c \le n$. Then apply the algorithm in the proof of Lemma 5.18 in [Combinatorial Commutative Algebra](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9780387223568).

Comment: Ok. +1 for the suggested answer. However a full proof is missing.